# I would like to merge the duplicates in the excel sheet

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have 4 fields, Primary phone(p1), secondary phone(p2), primary email(e1), secondary email(e2). 
If p2 field is empty, then the p1 value of new row should go to p2.

[image]

I am able to merge P number field, but unable to merge p email and se email
Please find the below code:

```
def merge_or_delete_contact(self, contact, contact_list):
        query_params = self.query_params(contact)
        if len(query_params):
            old_contact = contact_list.contacts.filter(query_params).exclude(id=contact.id).first()
            if old_contact:
                old_contact.secondary_phone_number = contact.primary_phone_number
                old_contact.secondary_email = contact.primary_email
                old_contact.name = contact.name if contact.name else old_contact.name
                contact.delete()
                old_contact.save()
                return old_contact
        return contact
```

```
def query_params(self, obj):
    query = Q(secondary_phone_number=obj.primary_phone_number)
    if obj.secondary_phone_number:
        query = query | Q(primary_phone_number=obj.secondary_phone_number)
    if obj.primary_email:
        query = query | Q(primary_email=obj.primary_email)
    if obj.secondary_email:
        query = query | Q(secondary_email=obj.secondary_email)
    return query
```